# Flask app : The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Why doesn't my add function work?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def index(name="Mona"):
    #name= request.args.get('name', name)
    return "Hello from {}".format(name)
@app.route('/add/num1/num2')
def add(num1, num2):
    return '{} + {} = {}'.format(num1, num2, num1 + num2)
app.run(debug=True, port=8002, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I get this error when I browse to `0.0.0.0:8002/add/1/4`

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Comment: For accessing @app.route('/add/num1/num2') you'd need to browse to 0.0.0.0:8002/add/num1/num2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the add method to the following and now it is working:

```
@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<int:num2>')
def add(num1, num2):
    return '{} + {} = {}'.format(num1, num2, num1 + num2)
```

Update: On a further note, if you want not to receive 404 error when entering floats, here's the code:

```
@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<int:num2>')
@app.route('/add/<int:num1>/<float:num2>')
@app.route('/add/<float:num1>/<int:num2>')
@app.route('/add/<float:num1>/<float:num2>')
def add(num1, num2):
    return '{} + {} = {}'.format(num1, num2, num1 + num2)
```